# Use angular-tree-component in "dotnet new angular" project?

Tags: angular, tree, dotnet-cli

When trying to integrate angular-tree-component into a project created with `dotnet new angular`, I consistently run into an exception:

> void(0) is not a function.

Either the tree never appears, or it appears briefly, but then the error happens and it disappears. I imagine this is due to a package versioning issue, as the component's own demo works fine. But I have no idea which package, or what a work-around might be.

I've [cross-posted this as an issue to the angular-tree-component forums](https://github.com/500tech/angular-tree-component/issues/405) and also made various attempts available as a [public repo](https://github.com/verybadcat/AngularTreeComponent).

Any ideas?

Comment: Their demo doesn't even work for me https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs Just hangs saying Loading Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the mobx-angular-debug 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.

Comment: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/tree ? maybe time to try another library?

Comment: avoid tree components if you need mobile friendly support

Comment: Your public repo url is broken.

Comment: @JGFMK what is not working for you and in which browser ?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bn-ng-tree-lib, try this angular tree npm

Answer (score 1):

I have just tested it myself and it was working on chrome version 73.0.3683.86.
I have used Visual studio code, but you can use anything you want.

1. Create a folder and open it with VS Code
2. Open a terminal and execute `dotnew new angular` command - this will create a .net core application
3. Execute `ng new tree-test` command - it creates an angular app names tree-test. Select `yes`, when prompted and then choose `scss` format
4. Execute `cd tree-test` - to change working folder to a newly created angular app
5. Execute `npm install --save angular-tree-component` - this will install your component to the application
6. Open `tree-test>src>styles.scss` file and add a line in there: `@import '~angular-tree-component/dist/angular-tree-component.css';` - this will make your tree styles work
7. Open `app.module.ts` file and add `import { TreeModule } from 'angular-tree-component';` to the header and set up import like this: `imports: [..., TreeModule.forRoot()]`
8. Open `app.component.html` file and replace everything with `<tree-root [nodes]="nodes" [options]="options"></tree-root>`
9. Open `app.component.ts` and replace all `AppComponent` class content with the following:

> ```
> nodes = [
>     {
>       id: 1,
>       name: 'root1',
>       children: [
>         { id: 2, name: 'child1' },
>         { id: 3, name: 'child2' }
>       ]
>     },
>     {
>       id: 4,
>       name: 'root2',
>       children: [
>         { id: 5, name: 'child2.1' },
>         {
>           id: 6,
>           name: 'child2.2',
>           children: [
>             { id: 7, name: 'subsub' }
>           ]
>         }
>       ]
>     }
>   ];
>   options = {};
> ```

10. run `ng serve` command, wait until it completes and open your browser in `http://localhost:4200`. You will see a nice tree there.